# Execute PHP script relative to html using JQuery, JSON

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have a file structure in place where I'm using SSIs (shtml) to populate pages with images and forward and back links between pages, all the files and links being searched for and populated are variables stored in arrays, echoed to JSON and accessed and utilized in JQuery, called by the HTML.

What I would like to do is have only a single .shtml page and it's accompanying content in one folder for ease of access and edibility, leaving my jquery and PHP in the root directory, so it doesn't have to be copied and pasted to each folder with the html.

The problem is that PHP (right now using a glob function) executes relative to itself and not relative to the html.

So how can I get the glob to look for files relative to the shtml without coming from the root directory? (Because I need everything to stay variable and relative each particular html file.)

Comment: Would I need to just suck it up and write the PHP and JS inline in my root shtml?

Comment: Could you not just point at the folder containing the files? `shtml/somefile.shtml`

Comment: The problem is it would be pointing at `*/*/images/*.jpg,etc` And thus would end up populating a page with every other pages' images in its siblings' folders.

Comment: Is there any way I could make the PHP script aware of the html calling it, or get it's filepath somehow?